# Настройка скрипта прелоадера для загрузки сайта

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование

Нужна ваша помощь с прелоадером для сайта. Лоадер работает до полной загрузки страницы, но на сайте стоит скрипт обратного звонка со стороннего сайта. Данный скрипт конкретно увеличивает время загрузки страницы и показа контента до 30 секунд, а без него 6 сек Можно ли как то настроить скрипт лоадера, чтоб сторонний скрипт, грузился после показа контента на странице?

```
<div id="loader-overflow">
  <div id="loader3" class="loader-cont">Please enable JS</div>
</div>


$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").imagesLoaded(function() {
        $(".loader-cont").fadeOut();
        $("#loader-overflow").delay(200).fadeOut(700);
    });
});
```

Comment: можно сделать, чтобы изначально скрипт вообще не подгружался, а только после того как страница полностью загрузится

Answer (score 0):

Подключите этот скрипт, где у вас находятся все js - new.js.
В этом скрипте будет содержаться подключение вашего стороннего скрипта -

```
window.onload = {
 document.write ('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/storonniscript.js" ></sc' + 'ript>');
}
```

То есть когда произойдет загрузка, то данный скрипт подключится

Comment: идея отличная, но сторонний скрипт не подключается...т.е не работает

Answer (score -1):

Вот так заработало, может кому сгодиться

```
window.onload = function() {    
$.getScript("/js/storonniscript.js");
};
```